# Is the graph planar?

Tags: graph-theory

Let the graph $G$ be connected. $G$ has 31 vertexes and 90 edges. Is it planar?
My attempt: if it was planar $\Rightarrow$ $v+f-e=2 \Rightarrow f=61$. Where does the contradiction come from this information? Thank's for help

Answer (score 4):

For a planar, connected graph, if $v\ge 3$, then $e\le 3v-6$. Thus
$$90\le 3\cdot 31-6,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508160/prove-that-a-graph-is-a-maximal-planar-graph-if-and-only-if-e-3v-%E2%88%92-6?rq=1
Is this what you're using? But there is such phrase as "maximal planar graph". So i thought I couldn't use that formula as I don't know anything if it's maximal or not. Could you explain a little?

Comment: There are also $K_{3,3}$ which satisfies the inequality, but it's nonplanar

Comment: The equation $v + f -2 =2$ implies that for any planar graph $G$, we have that $e \leq 3v-6$ (you should proof this to see why). The maximal planar graphs are for when equality holds, but the inequality holds for all planar graphs. Note that the inequality holds for all planar graphs, but the statement does not say anything about non-planar graphs. So the fact that $K_{3,3}$ satisfies the inequality is irrelevant.